# whats the difference between src file and Target file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I cloned a project from GitHub and it has src and target folders as shown below.

[image: Intellij Project structure]

Both folders got same files. I want to know the reason behind duplicated folder structures.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The target folder is where IntelliJ will keep the compiled versions of your Scala application files. As such, the files and folders within the target directory is automatically managed by IntelliJ and you should not place any of your application files here.

Comment: By IntelliJ and/or your build tool (SBT, Maven..).